# Export virtual environment created with venv to yaml file [no conda]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv, virtual-environment

I have created a virtual environment using:
`python3 -m venv env_name`.
I worked with this and installed all packages required for my work using `pip3`. Now I want to export this to a remote server. Which takes only the YAML file, and creates a conda environment. So how can I export the YAML file for my environment (`my_env`).
Note: I don't have conda installed, so I need a solution without conda. Thanks for the help.